Finding a path of given length with maximal relative weight
Let $G$ be a directed graph with vertices $V$ and edges $E \subset V\times V$. A path of length $n \geq 2$ in $G$ is a sequence of vertices $(i_{0},i_{1},\ldots,i_{n-1})$ such that $(i_{k},i_{k+1}) \in E$ for any $k \in \{ 0,1,\ldots,n-2 \}$. Suppose we are given with functions $\alpha \colon V \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\tau \colon V \to \mathbb{N}$. Is there an efficient algorithm to maximize the $\tau$-relative $\alpha$-weights
$$ \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha(i_{k})}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \tau(i_{k})} \to \max_{i}$$
over all paths $i=(i_{0},i_{1},\ldots,i_{n-1})$ of a given length $n$ and output an optimal path?
For example, in the case all $\tau_{i}$ are equal (so there is no relativity in the weights), there is an efficient algorithm working in $O(n \cdot d \cdot |V|)$, where $d$ is the mean degree of vertices, based on dynamic programming. But its idea fails when relativity is added.

Without restrictions like starting vertex, ending vertex, or distinct vertices, the maximum is likely to be achieved by going back and forth between two vertices.  Is that desired?

@RobPratt, in the graphs of my interest this is not the case. They have several tens of thousands of vertices, small mean degree (about 5-10) and dont have sinks or sources (so any path has an infinite prolongation to the past and future). In the limit as $n \to +\infty$, the maximum of relative weights is achieved on a simple cycle. But there are too many of them even to be enumerated. For sufficiently large $n$ (say n=1000) the maximal path should be a multiple repetition of a simple cycle (very short) plus a remainder. This simple cycle is likely the maximal one and carries the most weight.

@RobPratt, so this is why I am interested in a maximizing path. It allows to effectively extract the maximal simple cycle without enumerating and checking all of them.

Without fixed $n$, this is the tramp steamer problem, and the minimization version is the minimum cost-to-time ratio cycle problem, discussed in section 5.7 of Ahuja, Magnanti, Orlin, Network Flows (1993).  You can replace node weights with weights on all the outgoing arcs.
